# Determining actual args an Excel UDF was called with

Tags: c++, excel, user-defined-functions

I'm adding a user defined function to Excel with varargs-based signature in C++:

```
LPXLOPER MyFunction(...);
```

When Excel calls `MyFunction`, it passes it 30 arguments regardless of how many the user entered in the sheet. The extraneous ones are blank strings.

`MyFunction`, however, is designed to accept empty string arguments. As a result, I cannot tell valid empty strings apart from the extraneous ones sent by Excel.

A solution could be to obtain the contents of the actual cell where the user entered the function. However, I can't find a way of doing that from within the implementation of my function.

Could someone please suggest a way out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a simple way to get hold of the caller cell.

Use `excelApp->get_Caller()`;

Comment: how did you get the excelApp instance inside your UDF?

Comment: Oh. It's been a while. I don't remember and I don't have access to that code any more :(